# Image animations on Watchkit sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit

I would like to know if someone knows how to make sophisticated animations with CALayer class. In the watchkit documentation is the api for making an image sequence animation.

Answer (score 5):

I only have found how to make simple sequence animation. Add the sequence of image to your project:
[image]

And add the following snippet of code to setup the image control:

```
[self.imgSpriteAnimation setImageNamed:@"dragon-"];
[self.imgSpriteAnimation startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 60) duration:1.0 repeatCount:0];
```

In the following [post](http://celeri.es/image-animations-watchkit-sdk/) is explained in more detail how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Image sequence animations are the only animations available to third party developers in WatchKit at the present time.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but it may help. In is SO answer I show how to create dynamic image animations. [Is it possible to position views on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556113/is-it-possible-to-position-views-on-top-of-each-other/27556227#27556227)