# How to get the image from map in apple watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I am creating a map with custom image for annotation, I want an image from my map object.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `WKInterfaceMap` it is not possible to get the map image (at least not that I know of).  You can create a map image locally in your map extension and then set that image on a `WKInterfaceImage` or `WKInterfaceGroup`.  I am not sure what would be involved in creating a map image with MapKit.  I create map images from tiles for use in my app and set it as the background on a `WKInterfaceGroup` to create a UI that looks like this [Is it possible to position views on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556113/is-it-possible-to-position-views-on-top-of-each-other/27556227#27556227).