# Watchkit animation implementations: clock face, animated charts, circular progress bar

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, watchkit

I've seen some very basic demos of potential watchkit apps, and some appear to implement animations.  Examples might be:

- A clock face with a moving second hand or even minute hand.
- A bar chart with bars that animate in, or who shape changes with new real-time data.
- A circular progress bar who's bar animates from zero to the current value.

The only way I've seen so far to do animations is by a sequence of images over a duration:

```
[imageView startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 60) duration:1.0 repeatCount:0];
```

How would these previous animation examples generally be implemented?  I can't imagine they are all done with image sequences. I don't think one can even layer images, and coordinating placement would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all done with sequences of images.  Here is some code for how I animate movement on a map. [Is it possible to position views on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556113/is-it-possible-to-position-views-on-top-of-each-other/27556227#27556227)

**Edit**

You may also find these frameworks helpful.
https://github.com/frosty/Flipbook
https://github.com/radianttap/WatchRingGenerator

**2nd Edit**

Here is another great article on adding animation into your Watch App. http://david-smith.org/blog/2015/03/04/ailw-adding-bits-of-liveliness/