# How do you implement SpriteKit within a WatchKit extension app?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, watchkit, apple-watch

I am trying to extend a SpriteKit-based iPhone app to the Apple Watch, however given that Watch extensions do not use UIKit and UIViews (instead using WKInterfaceObject and its subclasses), I am not sure how I can setup my SKView and SKScene within the Watch extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is old, but just wanted to mention that in watchOS 3 you can use SpriteKit and SceneKit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use SpriteKit in a WatchApp.  You can ONLY use the UI elements provided for a Watch App.  You can't create custom UI elements.  The closest you can get is to create custom images in your watch extension running on the iPhone and set those in your Watch UI. See [Watchkit animation implementations: clock face, animated charts, circular progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859817/watchkit-animation-implementations-clock-face-animated-charts-circular-progre/28860254#28860254) for more info.