# Apple Watch Maps Animation

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

We are working on an app that requires an animation overtop of a map. this is a challenge because the map is a dynamic element and there are obvious limitations to the watch. Does anyone know a way to programatically take a snapshot of the mapview. I figure if we take the screenshot and then create an animation on the phone pushed to the watch this might solve this problem. Open to any other ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use something other than Apple's `mapview` you can draw the map yourself and then draw animations over it.  Here is an example of where I do this [Is it possible to position views on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556113/is-it-possible-to-position-views-on-top-of-each-other/27556227#27556227) (the animations in this example transferred too slowly over bluetooth and so I turned them off for the final product).  You could look at using something like MapBox (www.mapbox.com) to get map tiles and draw them.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. We will give this a shot!