# Animated annotation on WKInterfaceMap Watchkit

Tags: ios, animation, annotations, apple-watch, wkinterfacegroup

Is there anyway to have an animated annotation for `WKInterfaceMap` of Watchkit?

I have 35 images to form the animation. Currently I am using a `NSTimer` which calls

```
-(void)addAnnotation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location withImageNamed:(NSString *)name centerOffset:(CGPoint)offset
```

method with a different image names but the result is not efficient and the animation is not smooth as everytime it has to first remove the previous annotation and add a new one.

Any comment/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In WKInterfaceMap framework reference, it is mentioned, 'Maps can display no more than five annotations at a time.' - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceMap_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceMap

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did not mean that, I would like to have 35 images on the map. I would like to have an animated annotation and the animation in Apple Watch apps seem to be doable only using a group of images. So simply, how is it possible to have an animated pin on the map on the watch.

Comment: It can be achieved with WKInterfaceImage, check updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can not be achieved using WKInterfaceMap but it can be achieved using WKInterfaceImage. I have not implemented all steps but flow can be,

Generate snapshot of Map with selected lat-long in centre as UIImage    using MKMapSnapshotter,

```
MKMapSnapshotOptions * snapOptions= [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
CLLocation * Location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:23.0300 longitude:72.5800];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(Location.coordinate, 300, 300);
snapOptions.region = region;
snapOptions.size = CGSizeMake(300, 300);
snapOptions.scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

MKMapSnapshotter *mapSnapShot = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:snapOptions];
[mapSnapShot startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"[Error] %@", error);
        return;
    }

    UIImage *image = snapshot.image;//map image
    NSLog(@"%@",image);
    [self.mapImage setImage:image];
}];
```

- We already have Annotation image in resource So dynamically create
  merged images of annotation image to map snapshot image. If you want
  to add animation from top then you need to render annotation image
  from point (150,0) to (150,150) on map image. If you are generating
  15 images for animation then you need set for loop with 15 limit and
  each time increase Y of annotation image to 150/15 = 10. Keep track
  of these merged images in NSMutableArray. You may consider [this
  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27556227/602997) for rendering images.
- Use these dynamically generated NSMutableArray of images and set to
  Animation for WKInterfaceImage to achieve map annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not mean that, I would like to have 35 images on the map. I would like to have an animated annotation and the animation in Apple Watch apps seem to be doable only using a group of images. So simply, how is it possible to have an animated pin on the map on the watch.

Comment: MKMapSnapshotter is not available in Apple watch yet.