# Can I add button on Map in watchkit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

I'm trying to build an app for **Apple Watch OS 2**, so I was wondering is it possible to add buttons or images on top of the map?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't such a thing like "multiple layers", as you might call it, which would allow you to arrange a thing on top of another thing, in WatchOS yet.

So, I don't think, that the thing you want would work, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do your own tile rendering to do something like that.  I have four buttons over the top of my maps and I render custom waypoints and routes on the map.  To do that I have a custom tile render that generates an image that I set for the watch background and then I overlay buttons on top of it.  Here is some more info on how I overlay the buttons [Is it possible to position views on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556113/is-it-possible-to-position-views-on-top-of-each-other/27556227#27556227).  (One thing that has changed since that post is that I no longer break the background up into four images, I can just set the background as a single image.  Somehow I missed that when I initially read the API docs.  Also, I turned off the animations for watchOS 1 and I have them on for watchOS 2.)